# Как в MySql для Wordpress обрезать все после определенного символа

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в MySql для Wordpress в таблице wp_posts в поле post_title заменить все после знака "-".

На примере такого значения поля post_title:

"Купить телефон - Sony в Москве"

Нужно удалить все после знака "-", чтобы осталось только "Купить телефон - "

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Всем огромное, спасибо. Задача решена.

Comment: Если решена - стоит отметить вопрос решенным

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну  например

```
LEFT(field, 1 + INSTR(field, '-'))
```

или скажем

```
CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, '-', 1), '-')
```

Ну и ещё несколько вариантов...

Главное - не забыть обработать случай, когда тире в поле отсутствует (в вариантах, где это критично)...

Comment: Благодарю, Ваш ответ оказался наиболее практичным в применении.

Answer (score 3):

Добавьте в functions.php

```
function update_posts() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( 'admin' !== $current_user->user_login ) {
        return;
    }

    $args           = array(
        'numberposts' => - 1,
        'post_type'   => 'post',
    );
    $post_count     = 0;
    $post_processed = 0;
    $posts          = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        $post_count ++;
        $title   = $post->post_title;
        $pos = mb_strpos( $title, '-' );
        if ( false !== $pos ) {
            $post->post_title = mb_substr( $title, 0, $pos + 1 );
            wp_update_post( $post );
            $post_processed ++;
        }
    }
    echo 'Count: ' . $post_count . ', processed: ' . $post_processed;
}

add_action ('init', 'update_posts');
```

и обновите любую страницу сайта один раз, будучи зарегистрированным под `admin`. Или исправьте в коде `admin` на ваш логин администратора.

Потом уберите этот код.

Comment: +1. Ну хоть ты - надежда и опора новичков :)  Но стоило бы дописать про массу существующих плагинов поиска-замены с регулярками. или известный скрипт. Одноразовая же операция.

Comment: @SeVlad про плагины ты лучше напишешь))

Comment: Ээхх. Уговорил :)

Answer (score 3):

*Преамбула*.
*В случае с ВП - не нужно трогать базу. Нужно забыть о ней до максимально полного понимания ВП.

Для изменения чего-либо (в базе ли, логике ли и тд) нужно использовать [АПИ ВП](https://codex.wordpress.org/ru:API_WordPress).*

---

Конкретно по данному вопросу.
Для внесения одноразовых изменений в базу существует масса готовых плагинов (одноразового применения). В т.ч. и с поддержкой регулярок.
Напр. https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-regex/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/
и множество [других](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/search+replace).

Есть также [замечательный скрипт](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/).

А кто до сих пор страдает плагинофобией -  см [ответ **KAGG Design**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/787409/233741) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
JOIN wp_posts p2 ON p1.id = p2.id
SET wp_posts.post_title = SUBSTRING(p2.post_title, 1, POSITION('-' IN p2.post_title))
WHERE wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%-%';
```